# How to redirect from /senturia-nam-sai-gon/?gallery=170 to /senturia-nam-sai-gon/projects/nha-pho-thuong-mai-5mx12m/?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect https://senturia.com.vn/senturia-nam-sai-gon/?gallery=170
to https://senturia.com.vn/senturia-nam-sai-gon/projects/nha-pho-thuong-mai-5mx12m/
I tried this .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} gallery=170 [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /senturia-nam-sai-gon/project/nha-pho-thuong-mai-5mx12m/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it's not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine. I highly recommend making sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on the server. Also, make sure that the .htaccess file is located in the correct place. If your are using some CMS with a single index.php file, the .htaccess should sit on the same level as that file. If senturia-nam-sai-gon is an actual directory on your server with its own index.php file, then the .htaccess should sit in that folder.

Here is how I would do it in a CMS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)gallery=170 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^senturia-nam-sai-gon/ /senturia-nam-sai-gon/project/nha-pho-thuong-mai-5mx12m/? [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Detailed break-down:

- `RewriteEngine on` simply enables URL rewriting
- `RewriteBase /` sets the base of all URLs (in this case simply /)
- `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING (?:^|&)galler=170 [NC]` applies the following rule, if the GET parameters contain `gallery=170`. The `[NC]` flag makes the condition ignore upper- and lower-case
- `RewriteRule ^senturia-nam-sai-gon/ /senturia-nam-sai-gon/project/nha-pho-thuong-mai-5mx12m/? [R=301,L,NC]` redirects /senturia-nam-sai-gon/ to /senturia-nam-sai-gon/project/nha-pho-thuong-mai-5mx12m/ with a status-code of 301 ("Moved permanently"). The `?` at the end of the rule removes the querystring entirely. The `L` flag makes sure this is the last rule that gets applied. The `NC` flag does the same as before.

Comment: But actually, it's not work, i tried your code, but result is the same. Please Look at this picture, i screenshooted my .htaccess file. http://prntscr.com/oouek2

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. When I enter your URL in my browser's address bar, I get redirected to the desired page with a status-code of 301 (as can be seen in Chrome's developer tools). This might be a caching thing. Have you tried loading the page without using the cache? Your .htaccess looks absolutely fine and should work properly. I assume there is some kind of client error. What exactly _is_ your result, btw? Do you simply stay on `/senturia-nam-sai-gon/?gallery=170`?